# Can't make PHP work as FastCGI on Apache and Windows

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, php, fastcgi

I'm trying to run PHP as FastCGI with no success.

I made a *.conf file such on [mod_fcgid page](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html) but without a wrapper script.

Here is my conf:

```
# php5 as FastCGI executable
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 10000

# Uncomment the following line if cgi.fix_pathinfo is set to 1 in
# php.ini:
# FcgidFixPathinfo 1

<Location "D:/www">
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    Options +ExecCGI
    FcgidWrapper "C:/php/php-cgi.exe" .php

    # Customize the next two directives for your requirements.
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

The server start normally and fcgid_module is shown with `httpd -M`, but php files are server as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, try changing your line:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
```

to

```
AddHandler fcgid-script php
```

In order to get yourself up and running, you might also want to consider using mod_fastcgi (note, not mod_fcgid from Apache).  A dll is available here http://www.fastcgi.com/dist/mod_fastcgi-2.4.6-AP22.dll  Note that this is for Httpd 2.2.  (A dll for 2.4 is also available.)

Your config entry would look something like:

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    Alias /fcgi-bin "C:/www/cgi-bin"
    FastCgiServer "C:/www/cgi-bin/php-cgi.exe" -initial-env PATH=C:/php -initial-env PHPRC=C:/php
    AddHandler php-fastcgi .php
    <Location /fcgi-bin/>
        Options ExecCGI
        SetHandler php-fastcgi
    </Location>
    AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp .php
    Action php-fastcgi /fcgi-bin/php-cgi.exe
</IfModule>
```

You can probably get away with less, but it works for me on windows.